# What is the relationship between AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet and AbstractAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I'm trying to understand [this example project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java11/oauth2) which uses [Google's OAuth library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2) to let users login with their Google account.

Specifically, I'm trying to understand the relationship between [Oauth2AuthorizationCodeServlet.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine-java11/oauth2/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/Oauth2AuthorizationCodeServlet.java) and [Oauth2CallbackServlet.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine-java11/oauth2/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/Oauth2CallbackServlet.java). I know that Google's OAuth 2.0 library uses them to kick off the authorization flow and to handle the result after the user logs in, and I've read through the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-oauth-client/latest/index.html?com/google/api/client/extensions/servlet/auth/oauth2/AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet.html) for both abstract classes, but I'm wondering why both classes need to repeat the same logic?

- Both classes define `getUserId()` functions which return the same value.
- Both classes define `initializeFlow()` functions which return the same value.
- Both classes define `getRedirectUri()` functions which return the same value.

The code works fine, and I can see that the functions are called in this order:

1. `Oauth2AuthorizationCodeServlet#getUserId()`
2. `Oauth2AuthorizationCodeServlet#initializeFlow()`
3. `Oauth2AuthorizationCodeServlet#getRedirectUri()`
4. `Oauth2CallbackServlet#initializeFlow()`
5. `Oauth2CallbackServlet#getRedirectUrl()`
6. `Oauth2CallbackServlet#getUserId()`
7. `Oauth2CallbackServlet#onSuccess()`

But I'm wondering why the repeated functions in `Oauth2CallbackServlet` are necessary.

Why can't Google's OAuth 2.0 library use the values returned by the first class? Would it ever make sense for the corresponding functions to return different values? For example, would it ever make sense for their `getRedirectUrl()` functions to return different URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simplified diagram of google oauth login flow.

[image]

No 1. here represents `Oauth2AuthorizationCodeServlet`

No 2. here represents `Oauth2CallbackServlet`

Those are two different servlets, responsible for separate parts of login flow. 1 - redirects user to google login form with some url params like redirect url.
2 - handles callback after user finished with login, this servlet can access user info from google, perform actions on user behalf in google etc.

**To answer your questions:**

> Why can't Google's OAuth 2.0 library use the values returned by the first class?

Those are two separate servlets - it would be incorrect to perform communication between two separate servlets.

> Would it ever make sense for the corresponding functions to return different values? For example, would it ever make sense for their getRedirectUrl() functions to return different URLs?

In common scenario i don't think it makes sense to return different values from those servlets, but maybe some exotic scenario exists, where you have to support multiple google login callback urls for different use cases.